# Poco exception while sending request over http: SSL Exception: error:1000007e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: android, exception, twilio, chat

I am using Twilio Programmable Chat on android. While sending a message with the image file, I get this exception.

> Poco exception while sending request over http: SSL Exception: error:1000007e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

```
messagesObject.sendMessage(
                Message.options()
                        .withMedia(new FileInputStream(path), "image/*")
                        .withMediaProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStarted() {
                                Timber.d("Upload started");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(long bytes) {
                                Timber.d("Uploaded " + bytes + " bytes");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(String mediaSid) {
                                Timber.d("Upload completed");
                            }
                        }),
                new CallbackListener<Message>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Message msg) {
                        Timber.d("Successfully sent MEDIA message");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ErrorInfo error) {
                        Timber.e("Error sending MEDIA message");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please expand yourself a little more to complete understand your problem.

Comment: i get this error while sending media message in twilio chat. Text message is working fine.

Comment: @Ber.to please see question again, i had made some changes

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.
Solution: Upgrade to twilio latest depandancy i.e(3.0.0).
setDeferCertificateTrustToPlatform(boolean) to true.
It will work

https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/android/changelog#bug-fixes